# reducing migration time of a large size postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, configuration, pg-restore

We have a **postgresql 9.4** DB server that handles **2 DBs**, each **~800GB**. **No replication** is implemented yet.

We reduced pg_dump time with using -j & -Fd options to about 2 hours.

The problem is, we need to **separate DBs**, so we setup a fresh new server with Postgresql 9.6, but pg_restore takes a very long time (**~2 days**). I tried parallel pg_restore using -j (4, 8, 16, although VM has a **4 core CPU** and **16GB of RAM**) and tuned some parameters in **posotgresql.conf** like **shared_buffers**, **effective_cache_size**, **work_mem**, **maintenance_work_mem**, **wal_buffers** and so forth, but they didn't have any significant effect on reducing time of restore.

Even, I tried to restore **data and schema separately**, but same results.
I think the problem is we have **many tables with 15M records** that all have index and indices will increase restore time but I'm not sure of that

We thought about **replication**, so we do not have any significant downtime (after sync is complete, we can stop old/master server and change replica/slave to acts as a master server), but as **version of postgresql servers is not same**, it didn't work out! Updating main server postgresql version to 9.6 and then start replication will take such a time!

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `pg_upgrade` with the `--link option`

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a FAQ.

- `pg_upgrade` with `--link` (but understand that you can't easily go back);
- Logical streaming replication with `pglogical`
- Trigger-based logical replication with Londiste etc

Search for zero or low downtime PostgreSQL major version upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I'll research about methods you have introduced and will tell you the results.

Answer (score 0):

Although **pglogical** seems a great tool, but I didn't take and breaking stability and reliability of Debian's Postgresql packages.
In the other hand, I figured it out I can reduce time of restore with having a good balance between hardware resources and configurations in postgresql.conf file and **-j** option of pg_restore command.

For example restore time with 2*2 core CPU, 32 GB of RAM and **-j 32** took more than 16 hours.

Finally, pg_restore with 2*2 core CPU, 16 GB of RAM and **-j 16** worked out for me. It took 5 hours 17 minutes for me!